# What's wrong with my ingredients array ? Got an empty array

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, pg

I'm currently working on a cooking app and I have troubles with the API.

```js
IngredientsController.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let ingredients:Ingredient[] = []
    await pool.query({text:'SELECT * FROM Ingredients ORDER BY id'}, (error: Error, results: QueryResult) => {
        if (error) {
            throw(error);
        }
        for (let key in results.rows) {
            let ingredient:Ingredient = new Ingredient(Number(results.rows[key].id), results.rows[key].name);
            ingredients.push(ingredient);
        }
        res.status(200);
        res.json(ingredients);
    })
    console.log(ingredients)
    return res;
})
```

When I test the API on my browser, I can see the whole list of ingredients.

My problem is that the `console.log(ingredients)` instruction display an empty array.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my controller ?

As you can see in the code, I put an await instruction in the code but it is still not working.
Is it because I load the array inside the query function ?

Comment: You are mixing callbacks and promises ...  `pool.query(..., (error, result) => {...})` does not return a promise, thus it cannot be awaited

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `await` from the following:

```
    await pool.query({text:'SELECT * FROM Ingredients ORDER BY id'}, (error: Error, results: QueryResult) => {
        if (error) {
            throw(error);
        }
        ...
    })
```

To:

```
try {
  const results = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM Ingredients ORDER BY id');
  console.log(results);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
}
```

Once you see this working; add the looping construct back in; though, I'd probably map over `results.rows` to create the `ingredients` array.